# Can't read Integer in Stream after encoding it as UTF-8 instead of ASCII

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I had problems with Umlauts in ASCII so I encode my Stream as UTF-8 now, which works, but it brings up a problem. I normally read 4 Bytes before ARTIST to determine the length of ARTIST=WHOEVER using

```
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
string response = enc.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
int posArtist = response.IndexOf("ARTIST");
BitConverter.ToInt32(message, posArtist - 4);
```

This works for ASCII perfectly.

**The hex-editor examples are just to illustrate that reading the length doesn't work anymore like with ASCII**

Here is an example-screenshot from a hex-editor:
[image]

"ARTIST=M.A.N.D.Y. vs. Booka Shade" Length = 21

However that doesn't work for the UTF8-encoded stream.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

"ARTIST=Paulseq" Length = E but in the picture its 2E.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you clarify if the hex dump is before or after decoding?

Comment: Look at the the line `response.IndexOf("ARTIST")`. That index value is passed as a binary offset into `message`, whatever that is. IndexOf is a `String` method. This is exactly what I meant by mixing tools. You're analyzing a binary stream both as a String, and as a binary block. That is the second problem here, the first is that the data doesn't appear to be written correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your data is wrong - you actually have the character '\0' in the data where there should be binary zeroes

The problem lies in how you created this data, not in the reading of it

Comment: That's already encoded.
When reading the lengths I read the original byte-Array (message).

Comment: i have no idea what that means. For sure the dumped data you show cannot be fed into BitConverter. If you are trying to read other data that you havent shown then we cant help you

Comment: '\0' is a C# char literal that the compiler converts to *one* byte value, 00.  The dump shows *two bytes*.  Maybe the code that writes this has a "convert to C# source code" option, seems bizarre.  But yes, it comes down to how it was actually written.

Answer (score 3):

It is an utter mystery how you got 21 out of the ASCII data.  The shaded byte is in hex, its real value is 33.  There's no way you can get 21 out of BitConverter.ToInt32, that requires bytes values (in hex) 15 00 00 00.

This must have worked by accident but no idea what that accident might look like.  Post more code, including the code that writes this.

Comment: I attached some more code.
The hex-editor-shots are just to show you that reading the length like with ASCII-encoding doesn't work anymore. I know that these are hex-values.

Comment: That didn't help.  The ultimate flaw is that you expect binary data to be convertible to a string and back.  That just doesn't work anymore in Unicode.  It will fall victim to normalization and surrogates.  You need to dramatically change this, BinaryWriter or BinaryFormatter.  A low pain point that avoids hacking hex is XML serialization.  Or a database, SQL Compact is nice.

Comment: The length actually is 21h, 33 decimal.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are mixing tools. That is a binary stream. It should be read with a BinaryReader and written with a BinaryWriter. When writing text, use Encoder.GetBytes to get the raw bytes to write, and when reading use Encoder.GetString on the raw bytes read. BinaryWriter/Reader have methods for values (like lengths) directly.

Answer (score 2):

Only the strings should be UTF-8 encoded/decoded.  If you're passing other (non-string) values in binary, the encoders they will destroy them.

Comment: Oh that sounds bad.
Now I'm randomly seeking for ARTIST in the buffer and parse the rest of the string by reading the length and then the rest.
That would mean I have the parse all the stream correctly.